# Using reduce to see if two values of an array produce zero in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been tasked with the following:

> Write a method that takes an array of numbers. If a pair of numbers
>   in the array sums to zero, return the positions of those two numbers.
>    If no pair of numbers sums to zero, return `null`.

```
function two_sum (arr) {
  var newarr = arr.reduce(function(arr, previous, current){
    if (previous + current === 0) { 
      arr.push(current);
        return arr;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    }, []);
   return newarr;
}
```

I thought you had to use the two additional arguments to get at the initial array values—like:

```
  var newarr = arr.reduce(function(arr, previous, current, i, a){
    if ((a[i] + a[i + 1]) === 0) {
```

But that didn't work...
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't really strike me as a problem to be tackled by array#reduce, but it's possible I'm not really thinking about it properly. There's a pretty easy (and `O(n)`) approach using maps (`{}` objects in JS) that will probably serve you better.

Comment: Thanks CollinD, I'll check it out...but this was part of an array (ack sorry—bad pun) of questions from a cold school entrance exam!

Comment: I'll provide the map solution as an answer. It doesn't technically address your requirements of using reduce, but it may be worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a map pretty easily. The approach is to iterate over the map, and for each index `i` and value `v` we store

```
map[-v] = i
```

We then check if `map[v]` is defined, and if so we've found a pair. If we get to the end without finding a pair, then we can return null.

Note that we actually check for `map[v]` first here, otherwise a single value of `0` would come back as its own pair.

```
var two_sum = function(arr) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var val = arr[i];
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
            return [i, map[val]];
        }
        map[-1 * val] = i;
    }
    return null;
};
```

The above code is untested, but I believe it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `reduce`:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,-3,4,-4,5,6,-6];

const res = array
  .reduce((acc, cur, i) => (i < (array.length - 1)) 
    ? ((cur + array[i+1]) === 0) ? acc.concat(i) : acc 
    : acc
  , []).map(n => [n, n+1])
  
console.log(res) // array of indexes [ [2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8] ]
```

You can find proper arguments order and meaning in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). In `reduce` your `previous value` is actually an accumulator, a result returned by previous iteration, rather than a previous element of your array.

Comment: Oh, we need positions of both numbers. I thought we need only the first number's position. Fixed it, thanks.